# How can i get the Subsidiary of Location in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Can someone help me, how can i get the subsidiary on of specific location in and place in the drop down list in netsuite. I have a task that when the user click the radio button, the drop down list will show the specific subsidiaries of radio button value. i use cleint script on this task. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Field with Type of List/Record and List/Record of Subsidiary and set the Sourcing and Filtering accordingly. No script is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there's a form creating using suitelets. The task is when the radio button click on the specific subsidiary the drop down list will change according to the subsidiary

Comment: If that is the case you need to reload your Suitelet and pass the value of the radio button to properly fill in the drop down list because nlobjField is read only if you access it from a client script.

Comment: @ vVinceth How can i get first the list belongs to subsidiary? Im using this function getSelectValue but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to create a search and filter it out according to your need and put the result of your search on your drop down list.

Comment: @ vVinceth How? Do you have sample on this search filter?

Comment: Or an API that i need to know for the search and filter

Comment: From SuiteAnswers simply type Search Sample and you will find different search sample there.

Comment: One question, its possible to alter the value of drop down list using jquery?

Comment: the NetSuite dropdown is different from the standard HTML dropdown so it is not possible.

Comment: How can i alter or change the drop down list?